# openSUSE Linux Kiosk Setup

Tags: linux, opensuse, kiosk

Working on setting up a kiosk with openSUSE, where users can only view a single webpage. Obviously open to any Linux distro. Also would prefer to use Gnome.

I'm wanting only Firefox to be available (which will be displaying a local webpage), a link on the desktop and the home page to open full screen when booted up and logged in automatically.

Just interested in some guidance, or if there are any tools that could be used to 'lock down' the system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with it, but you should probably use [Suse Studio](http://susestudio.com/).

Comment: Yeah, i've heard of Suse Studio, but never really used it. Now is the time i think!

Answer (score 1):

Rather old, but in-detail article on locking the user in a fullscreen browser with fvwm by one of fvwm developers: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LGNET/128/adam1.html - as far as I see, all of commands must still work.

You can additionally assign no-ops to firefox hotkeys with fvwm or use [R-kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/) to make the lock-down even more efficient. I wouldn't even show the desktop or icons - it's unnecessary.

As you're done with this, just use any firewall supporting whitelists and forbid all the pages but these you want users to browse.

I would as well forbid firefox to search for updates to addons so that users could not see the windows they don't need to.

Comment: Thanks Roman, that looks interesting. I wont have any trouble setting up Firefox, as there are plenty of plugins available to turn that into a kiosk...I'm not too familiar with fvwm, but i'll look into it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be necromancing, but hopefully it'll help others..

This sounds exactly what you want: [Creating a Web-Kiosk image](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB%3aKIWI_Cookbook_Kiosk_System)

SuSE studio is built on top of KIWI, but this will give you more customization and a better understanding of what SuSE Studio is actually doing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through a similar exercise and I am quite pleased with results. I posted up the whole setup here: [How to configure kiosk with Wayland / Xorg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344374/how-to-configure-kiosk-with-wayland-xorg) My setup required one webpage only, hence I chose Surf browser in -K mode - with everything disabled but the left-click. You can set whatever else you like for browser. Please feel free to ask, if anything unclear.