# linux - autologin and run X11 app in loop

Tags: linux, x11, browser, autologin

I got some project where need to have simple workstation with running only web browser. It should boot -> autologin and run browser; when somebody will close browser it should start it again.

I have made autologin in console, and run browser with startx from .bashrc but I stuck on browser reopen, now  when somebody will close browser workstation is going back to bash in tty and not starting X11 with browser again.

Is there any nice trick to keep browser life in loop?

regards
Peval

Answer (score 3):

How about a system where user cannot close the browser? I recently made a system where it is not really possible. The added bonus is that it is pretty fast. Essentially it is in i3 window manager with virtual consoles disabled and browser started in kiosk mode. You can read about full setup here: [How to configure kiosk with Wayland / Xorg?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344374/how-to-configure-kiosk-with-wayland-xorg)

But of course it is possible to replicate this setup with firefox in kiosk mode. I have not done the latter myself, but there are several good descriptions on how to do this e.g. http://www.brighthub.com/internet/google/articles/107735.aspx and a newer one is here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mkiosk/

As to your question how to restart the process - it is well described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696839/how-do-i-write-a-bash-script-to-restart-a-process-if-it-dies

HTH

Comment: No problem. When I first set this up to me 2 full days with trial and error. But I am pleased that no keyboard shortcuts are working, except one I set up for shutdown. Likewise right mouse not working and as there are no close buttons, closing the window doesn't work either. There is no menu bar so one can't select `file - quit`. Still a script checking for browser running and restarting could be good and is doable.